# How to build a iPhone/Ipad application builder

Tags: iphone, ios4

What is the approach/methodology to build a iPhone app builder so that end users can develop apps without using code like they are doing in [Mobile Roadie](http://mobileroadie.com/). How will the xcodeproj/ipa file will be generated from the website when we create our own app in websites like Mobile Roadie? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to look at the `xcodeproj` file format (right click/ctrl click and show files, look at the `xml`, `scheme`, `perspective` files etc), and then try to write your own generator to use that output format. I doubt very much Apple would be okay with you competing with their Xcode for an iOS IDE, though.

Comment: The scope of this question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. Its a Big Question -

First what you need is to crate a fully featured project that mobile roadie gives you when you select all the modules. You need to build this project keeping a settings.xml file in your resource this file should control the modules in your poject like if you want to disable a module in the app then you can disable that from this xml. You can also configure your other parts of the app using this xml like color theme and other settings like mobile roadie provide in there web interface.

Now you need to build a web interface to generate this settings.xml file. User choose modules, color theme, Images etc. and they get entered in the xml file. and finally a settings.xml file gets generated.

Third - now you have to manually download this xml file and drag in your project file and build the app.

Fourth - upload the app on appstore manually. (There is no automatic process for step 3 and 4 you have to do it manually)

Well the above approach is not very precise we your question if very very broad.

Comment: Thank you Saurabh. Can you please suggest any references or links on this matter.